# Can this be done with SQLAhclemy / Python?

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a database in SQL, with python. Was wondering if it would be possible to group things together like the below image? (I know we can do this in Excel. But I was wondering if it would be possible to do it in SQL?)

[image: capture]

If it is not possible to do this in SQL, What do you suggest I can do that would provide similar results?

Comment: In the *visual* or in the *data* sense?

Comment: @jake wong Do you want the database schema for this data? I mean how this data could be stored in relational database so that you can manipulate it with SQLAhclemy / Python?

Comment: @Mehari Thanks for ur reply. I'm quite new to relational databases. But if this was structured this way, would I be able to manipulate it in SQLAlchemy / Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to achieve that with SQL. All you have to do is create a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE data (
    names TEXT,
    counter INT,
    ratio1_2012 INT,
    ratio2_2012 INT,
    ratio3_2012 INT,
    ratio4_2012 INT,
    ratio1_2013 INT,
    ...
);
```

Of course, this is not a very "pretty" solution and so it might be better to have one table per year:

```
CREATE TABLE data2012 (
    names TEXT,
    counter INT,
    ratio1 INT,
    ...
)

...
```

In the end, which approach you want to take depends on how much data you have and how much of a concern is space vs query execution speed to you. If you have two tables, you have a lot of duplicated data (all names for instance).

Visually, either method works fine you just have to adapt the frontend code in the necessary way.

Comment: A much better solution would be to have a `year` column, then it will be possible to `group by year`.

Comment: @David Gomes Yes thats true. I think what you mentioned by grouping it via year would be easier to manage..